# flattening a 3d object to make a 2d stencil?

Tags: edit-mode

long story short im trying to figure out how to take this 3d Bracer I modified and flatten everything almost to a sheet of paper. There are pepakura programs that will do this if you are making things out of paper but that isn't what I need. I want to take this rounded gauntlet and flatten it so I can turn it into a stencil for foam (since foam can be shaped into a round object) I have been looking for hours trying to figure this out but I cant.. I have tried turning this thing into an .svt but the file is empty when I import it. Any tips on how to do this? Overview: Flatten 3d object, print out stencil to cut into foam. Any help will be greatly appreciate as im almost bald from pulling my hair out over it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Scaling to zero on Z axis will be enough?

Comment: I did what you said and that may work... my question is will it keep its dimensions I had set for it prior? Also, how would I save it to an image that would be exact dimensions I laid out for it? for instance, its 9 inches long and I need to be able to print it as a 9 inch image

Comment: If you only need an image, just place a camera above object and set it to ortho mode (no need to scale an object). Adjust camera ortho scale and resolution to match object bounds. Here is some info on pixels and inches: https://www.picmonkey.com/standard-photo-print-sizes

Comment: im still new to blender as im off and on with it. so I apologize but adjusting the camera ortho scale and resolution to match the object bounds is Greek to me. I have the camera in ortho mode and its above the image. I have tried to go into render mode also but that is a blank screen...